# Finding the Variance of two continuous variables

Tags: probability, geometry

The following problem is from the book "Probability and Statistics". It is part of the Schaum Outlines series.
Problem:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables having joint density function:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x + y & \text{for }0 \leq x \leq 1,\, 0 \leq y \leq 1 \\
0 &  \text{otherwise}  \\
\end{cases} \\
$$
Find $Var(x)$.
Answer:
\begin{align*}
Var(x)  &= E(x^2) - E(x)^2 \\
E(x^2) &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^2(x+y) \, dy \, dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^3 + x^2y \, dy \, dx \\
E(x^2) &= \int_0^1 x^3 y + \frac{x^2y^2}{2} \Big|_0^1 \, dx = \int_0^1 x^3 + \frac{x^2}{2} \, dx \\
E(x^2) &= \frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^3}{6} \Big|_0^1 = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{6+4}{24} \\
E(x^2) &= \frac{5}{12} \\
\end{align*}
Now we need to find $E(x)$.
\begin{align*}
E(x) &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x(x+y) \, dy \, dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^2 + xy \, dy \, dx \\
E(x) &= \int_0^1 x^2y + \frac{x^2y^2}{2} \Big|_0^1 \, dx  = \int_0^1 x^2 + \frac{x^2}{2} \, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{3x^2}{2} \, dx \\
E(x) &= \frac{3x^3}{6} \Big|_0^1 = \frac{1}{2} \\
Var(x) &= \frac{5}{12} - {\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) }^2 = \frac{5}{12} - \frac{1}{4} \\
Var(x) &= \frac{1}{6} \\
\end{align*}
However, the book gets:
$$ \frac{11}{144} $$

Now lets look at:
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x + y \, dy \, dx $$
This integral should evaluate to $1$.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x + y \, dy \, dx &= \int_0^1 xy + \frac{y^2}{2} \Big|_0^1 \\
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x + y \, dy \, dx &= \int_0^1 x + \frac{1}{2} \, dx \\
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x + y \, dy \, dx &= \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x}{2} \Big|_0^1 \\
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x + y \, dy \, dx &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1
\end{align*}
The integral does evaluate to $1$.

Comment: Can you double check the definition of the joint distribution? Is it $0 \leq x \leq 1$? I don't think so, since in that case the overall integral would not be equal to $1$.

Comment: @dfnu I fixed the limits on $x$. It is $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: then there must be some problem with the definition. If that's $f(x,y)$, then $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y) dx dy \neq 1$$.

Comment: @dfnu I do not agree with your evaluation of the integral. I posted how I computed its value and got $1$. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: i don't quite follow you. Where did the $e^{-x}$ disappear?

Comment: @dfnu I am sorry, I have the question stated wrong. I will fix it.

Comment: The second $E(x)$ row has a $x^2 y^2/2$ term which should be $x y^2/2$.